# What do I do if a method in one class uses a method from another?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have this class (in a file named "**occ_grid.py**"):

```
class Grid:
   def __init__(self, width, height, occupancy_value):
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
      self.cells = []

      # initialize grid to all specified occupancy value
      for row in range(0, self.height):
         self.cells.append([])
         for col in range(0, self.width):
            self.cells[row].append(occupancy_value)

   def set_cell(self, point, value):
      self.cells[point.y][point.x] = value

   def get_cell(self, point):
      return self.cells[point.y][point.x]
```

And I have another class/method(s) (in the file "**worldmodel.py**"):

```
class WorldModel:
   def __init__(self, num_rows, num_cols, background):
      self.background = occ_grid.Grid(num_cols, num_rows, background)
      self.num_rows = num_rows
      self.num_cols = num_cols
      self.occupancy = occ_grid.Grid(num_cols, num_rows, None)
      self.entities = []
      self.action_queue = ordered_list.OrderedList()


   def is_occupied(self, pt):
      return (self.within_bounds(pt) and
         occ_grid.get_cell(self.occupancy, pt) != None)
```

Notice how "**def is_occupied**" uses the method "get_cell". The thing is, "get_cell" is in a different file and it's a method in a different class. I thought about creating a new "grid" object, but I'm confused on where in my code I should create this object.

Comment: You asked a similar question before, and the issues are the same.  You seem to be thinking of a method as just an isolated function that you call, but that's not how it works.  Think of a method like a button or switch on an object: you press it and something happens.  It doesn't make sense to push the button without having the object there.  Likewise, it doesn't make sense to call the method without creating the object.  The question is, what does an object of class `Grid` represent, what does an object of class WorldModel represent, and what is the relationship between those two things?

Comment: Right, so I was thinking of creating an object inside of "is_occupied". Something like this: obj = occ_grid.Grid(640, 480, 0). And then change the second line in the body of "is_occupied" to: obj.get_cell(....). And of course, I'd put "import occ_grid" at the top. I'm just unsure if I'm on the right track. :(

Comment: Right, but the question is why would you create that object?  It doesn't generally make much sense to create an object just to call a method on it.  The question is what does the object *represent*, and what role does that play in the logic of your program?  In other words, what is a Grid and where/why do you need one?

Comment: So the playing screen's actually split up into a grid (there's a different image on each "square" of the playing screen). I think that's what grid refers to. And I'm guessing that the grid system also helps determine how far an image moves across the screen/other calculations in the program.

Answer (score 4):

You're pretty close.  It's just:

```
self.occupancy.get_cell(pt)
```

---

You *could* write:

```
occ_grid.Grid.get_cell(self.occupancy, pt)
```

and that would be **equivalent** -- But, that'd be pretty **unidiomatic**.

Comment: Is there a way to do it by creating an object??

Comment: What do you mean?  You already created the object:  `self.occupancy = occ_grid.Grid(num_cols, num_rows, None)`

Comment: Oh! Oops, forgot about that, thanks! So "self.occupancy" is an object right?

Comment: @Karen -- Technically it's an "instance of Grid".  If you're on python3.x, it's also an "instance of object", but not if you're on python2.x.  In an informal conversation, I think that a lot of people wouldn't be too averse to calling a class instance an object, but don't use it in a formal discussion :-)...

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Grid` at all from the file `worldmodel.py`, you need to `import` the `Grid` class.

You can do this in two possible ways.

1. `import occ_grid`. If you do this, you will have to access `Grid` with `occ_grid.Grid`
2. `from occ_grid import Grid`. Then you can use it with just `Grid`.

mgilson's answer is very clear about how to use it after you import it.